# avoid infinite recursion in core data parsing JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, core-data, recursion

```
- (void)tranformJSONItems:(NSArray *)jsonItems inCoreDataItem:(Item *)item {
/* Get the managed object context */
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
[jsonItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *jsonItem, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    Item *newItem = (Item *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Item class]) inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    newItem.label = jsonItem[@"label"];
    newItem.itemID = [self.numberFormatter numberFromString:jsonItem[@"id"]];
    if (nil!=item) {
        [item addSubItemsObject:newItem];
    }
    NSArray *subitems = jsonItem[@"items"];
    if (nil!=subitems) {
        [self tranformJSONItems:subitems inCoreDataItem:newItem];
    }
}];
if (nil==item)
    [self saveChanges];
}
```

I want to make an application that will parse JSON and transform it into Core Data, but the JSON that I have is very weird and difficult (it's nested and recursive).

In my JSON I have an `NSDictionary` of results which have many arrays of items. Each 'principal' item has a label, an ID, and another Item (which is a subitem).

When i'm using this recursive function, but my problem is my recursive function is infinite:
all my principal items have an id like (100,200,...) so I used a modulus 100 in my predicate for the principal item. My subitems all have an ID corresponding to their Principal item. For example for 100 you have subitems that have IDs like 101 102 .. I'm using a max and min predicate for those (I'm using `NSRange`) for my idToLoad, a location for my `NSminPredicate`, and an `NSMaxRange` for my `NSmaw` predicate.

Comment: Can we see some of the JSON, and a description of what the results of parsing that JSON would be?

Comment: `{
  "status": true,
  "code": 0,
  "display": true,
  "message": null,
  "results": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "0100",
        "label": "Actualités",
        "cover": null,
        "coverFrom": null,
        "coverTo": null,
        "coverOrder": null,
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "0101",
            "label": "Actualité / Infos",
            "cover": null,
                                ....`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of always inserting a new item, implement the find-or-create pattern for a particular `itemID`.

Write a fetch request that returns all `Item` instances with a particular `itemID` (hopefully that's an array of just one). Then, write a class method on `Item` (or on `NSManagedObject` if you insist, but your code will be easier to write/read if you subclass `NSManagedObject`). That class method takes as parameters an `NSManagedObjectContext` and an `itemID`, invokes your fetch request, and returns either the matching `Item` instance. That's the "find" part in "find-or-create".

Now, write another class method, accepting the same parameters as your "find" method above. This method performs the fetch. If a match is found, that instance is returned. If a match is not found, then insert a new `Entity`, initialize it with the `itemID`, and return that. This is the "find-or-Create": it always returns an instance with the right `itemID`, and never creates a new one unless needed.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but in meanwhile i tried to do somthing else, i added in my model a string with the ParentID, it's equal to NULL if it's a Parent and if it's a subItem or a ChildItem, it will have the same ParentId of it's Parent !! and i wanna change the minimum of my code!! do you have any suggestion of how i could do that! because i'm a little lost :(

Comment: Instead of using ParentID strings, just make a direct link (a relationship) between parent and child. It sounds like you might be thinking in too much of a database metaphor. Core Data is an object graph, not a database. Just make connections. Don't worry about keys.

Comment: This is almost what i did (i removed the recurcive relationships beteween item an itself and i used a single entity Item and add the ParentID like an attribute if the ParentID = nil then it's a Parent else it's a child and i used that in my predicates, it almost worked good except i had a another problem right now i'm guessing it's the NSFertechedReslutController Fault :p ... the problem is i have mutitple instance of the same Item (subItem) every time and i click on the back buttom it's fetched the same objects over and over again !!